# Can I use abesse with hinc, inde, and others?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

Is it idiomatic in classical Latin to combine the verb *abesse* with *hinc*, *inde*, or other such pronouns meaning "from somewhere"?
This is surely an at least intelligible way to say "to be away from here/there", but what I do not know is whether that would strike anyone as odd.
Of course I could find a way around such combinations, but I would like to know whether they are possible, not least because *inde abest* is such a compact expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find a couple of examples for hinc+abesse. At least, the construction is attested in Classical times. Not sure whether there were other more frequent, equivalent constructions.

Cicero:

> nunc contra et vidisse mihi multum videris, cum prope desperatis his rebus te in Graeciam contulisti, et hoc tempore non solum sapiens, qui **hinc absis**, sed etiam beatus. ([Cic. Fam. 7.28](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0009:book=7:letter=28&highlight=absis%2Chinc))
>
> *Now, however, on the contrary you seem to me to have been long-sighted for having settled in Greece when things here were in a desperate condition, and at the present crisis not only to be wise for **being abroad**, but happy as well* (Shuckburgh, 1908)

Plautus:

> Quo nihil invitus addas: talentum magnum. non potest triobolum **hinc abesse**. proin tu vel aias vel neges. ([Pl. Rud. 5.2](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0108%3Aact%3D5%3Ascene%3D2).40:45)
>
> *That you mayn't be adding anything against your inclination, a great talent; it's not possible for three obols **to be bated thence**; then do you say either "yes" or "no" at once.* (Riley, 1912)